# how to console log dim value in object

Tags: javascript

Currently I have the following code.  This is on `Fancybox` pop up window.  I'm not sure if that's relevant or not.

```
        $.fancybox.open({
        href: "#preview_image_img",
        title: "This is only a preview text may be adjusted to look its best.",
        closeBtn    : true,
        openEffect  : 'elastic',
        closeEffect : 'elastic',
        scrolling   : 'no',
        overlayShow: false,  
        fitToView: true,
    afterLoad : function( instance, current ) {
        console.log(instance);
    }
         })
```

`afterLoad` I `console.log` this object from the callback 'instance'. It appears on my console like so.

[image]

It's a list of an object with a bunch of methods etc.
if I console.log instance.key, instance.content etc all those return a value.  When I do instance.dim (which coincidently is the one I need) I get undefined.  How can I get the value of that?

[image]

Comment: It's being set after your log statement runs.  `console.log` writes a reference to the object to the console, which doesn't get resolved until you expand it.

Comment: See also [console.log() async or sync?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23392111/console-log-async-or-sync)